# Simple HTML DOM Memory issue

Tags: php, html, mysql, csv, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to use PHP Simple HTML Dom Parser to parse some information from SQL query results. But it seems, that there is some HUGE memory problem with it. I create an html table using the SQL query results and then export the html table to a csv file. I am really new to this so my code is not the most efficient one. When I my query results are small the csv file is created successfully. But when the query results are large, the exported csv file does not have any sql results and instead shows this :

> Fatal error:  Call to a member function find() on boolean in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test.php on line 101

This is my function that takes the sqlresult and creates an html table and then exports it into a csv file:

```
 echo sql_to_html_table($sqlresult, $delim="\n" );

function sql_to_html_table($sqlresult, $delim="\n") {
// starting table
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$htmltable =  "<table>" . $delim ;
$counter   = 0 ;
// putting in lines
//while( $row = $sqlresult->mysqli_fetch_assoc()  ){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlresult)) {
if ( $counter===0 ) {
// table header
$htmltable .=   "<tr>"  . $delim;
foreach ($row as $key => $value ) {
      $htmltable .=   "<th>" . $key . "</th>"  . $delim ;
  }
  $htmltable .=   "</tr>"  . $delim ;
  $counter = 22;
 }
  // table body
  $htmltable .=   "<tr>"  . $delim ;
  foreach ($row as $key => $value ) {
      $htmltable .=   "<td>" . $value . "</td>"  . $delim ;
  }
  $htmltable .=   "</tr>"   . $delim ;
 }
 // closing table

$htmltable .=   "</table>"   . $delim ;
 // return
//return( $htmltable ) ;
$html = str_get_html($htmltable);

header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=sample.csv');

$fp = fopen("php://output", "w");

foreach($html->find('tr') as $element)
{
$td = array();
foreach( $element->find('th') as $row)
{
    $td [] = $row->plaintext;
}
fputcsv($fp, $td);
$td = array();
foreach( $element->find('td') as $row)
{
    $td [] = $row->plaintext;
}
fputcsv($fp, $td);
}
fclose($fp);
}
```

I have tried throwing an exception after $html = str_get_html($htmltable); like this:

```
if (!str_get_html($htmltable)) {
throw new exception('exception') ; 
}
```

and when I try to run the code my browser gives me this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'exception' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test.php:96 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/test.php(62): sql_to_html_table(Object(mysqli_result), '\n') #1 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test.php on line 96

Comment: Why are you going from sql, to html to csv? Why not use mysql's native csv export function?

Comment: I am basically developing a frontend using php. So i need to select an SQL query from a drop down menu and then click a button to generate and save the csv file. I know how to use the csv export function to save the file but my boss wants to save it using a pop-up wondow.

Comment: Well your error doesn't signify anywhere that there is any memory issue. It says your are trying to call the function find() on a boolean on line 101. I assume that is this line: foreach($html->find('tr') as $element) if so what does $html contain, I would print_r($html); to find the contents to see if it is a string or a boolean and go from there

Comment: But I mentioned before that when I run a an SQL script that has a few number of rows in its result, it works perfectly fine. This problem only arises when I use an sql script that has a large number of rows in its result. Do you still think there is no memory issue?

Comment: I was going on the fact that no memory error was posted. Most DOM loaders will load the lines into memory one by one. How many results are we talking? What Memory error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any memory error. I am sorry for the confusion. We are talking about 46000 rows here. When I try to print the result in the browser, it gets stuck for some time and starts displaying the rows and this also introduces a lag in the browser.

Comment: Yes, you're certainly going to get memory and performance issues with 46000 `str_get_html` calls. My advice is to [switch to this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/) but also refactor your code, take the include out of the function because that's just weird and clean things up to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at a copy of simple_html_dom.php from SourceForge, this sounds like expected behavior for a sufficiently big HTML string.  I see that str_get_html() has a check that will cause it to return false if the size of the string is greater than MAX_FILE_SIZE.  And MAX_FILE_SIZE is defined with:

```
define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 600000);
```

So it looks like simple_html_dom won't handle any string bigger than about 600kb.  Since that's a built-in limitation, I guess your options are to either try to change the limit and see what happens or use a different library.

Alternatively, you could just skip the HTML portion altogether.  If you need to generate the HTML for other purposes, that's fine, but there's no reason you can't bypass this problem by just building the CSV directly from the database results rather than from the HTML.

Comment: I am really new to this and I have no idea how to get the CSV results directly from the database rather than the HTML. could you help me a bit on this?

Comment: Well, just use what you already have for building up the HTML.  Right now you're getting the data from MySQL, turning it into HTML, and turning the HTML into CSV.  It's the same data, so there's no reason you couldn't just do your fputcsv() directly on the database result when you loop through them.  The HTML is completely unnecessary for generating the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a little easier to understand:

```
function sql_to_csv($sqlresult, $delim = "\n") {

    // Loop each result into a csv row string
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlresult)) {

        // Create/reset a var to hold the csv row content
        $csvRow = '';

        // Append each column value comma separated
        // Be warned of column values containing commas
        foreach ($row AS $columnValue) {
            $csvRow .= $columnValue . ',';
        }

        // Remove the trailing comma from the final column
        rtrim($csvRow, ',');

        // Send your CSV row to the browser
        echo $csvRow . $delim;
    }

    header('Content-type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=sample.csv');
}
```

There are various issues with this approach not limited to, large output buffers, columns with multi-commas ...etc I recognise these problems but wanted to give an early approach to the solution instead of a large block of text.

The easiest way to debug PHP code is to run it with de-bugg outputting, the following may help you if the above is not useful:

```
var_dump($variable);
exit;
```

This will enable you to see the contents of the variable at run time, and may give better indication to your exception, given the line-number in your exceptions.

Goodluck.